# Maintain volume bone constraint 2x too big

Tags: bones, constraints, scale

I'm using Blender 2.79 and have a pretty plain scene. Cube (2x2x2) and a plane.

I added vertex group called cube to the cube, assigned all vertices to the vertex group, added a single bone, called it cube. Added an armature modifier to the cube.

Enter pose mode on the bone, add bone constraint maintain volume, leave at default Y,1,World,1 and scale the bone by 0.5 in the world z axis (bone y) now it looks too stretched.

I measured it with a new cube and it's 5.65685x5.65685x0.5, giving a volume of 16 instead of 8.
Is this a bug, am I misunderstanding how it should work or have I done something wrong?